# How to bond two container id in DOM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-easyui

In my project, I use easyui-layout, which has west and center region.

When i click easyui-linkbutton announcement, oat.php will return table content which will be included in cenDiv successfully.

Here is my js code:

```
function corpAnn()
{
var oaAnn="annIn";
 $.ajax({
        dataType:'html',
        type:"POST",
        url:"oat.php",
        data: {oaAnn:oaAnn},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#cenDiv').html(data);
        }
      });
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="firDiv" class="easyui-layout">
    <div id="wesDiv" data-options="region:'west',split:true" >
    </div>
    <div id="cenDiv" class="easyui-layout" data-options="region:'center',title:''">
    </div>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="corpAnn()">announcement</a><br />
```

Here is oat.php code:

```
echo '<div id="tbbs" class="easyui-panel" title="Panel Footer" style="width:100%;height:80%;border:1px solid #A9A9A9 ;" data-options="footer:\'#ft\'">';
echo '<table id="bbs" class="cenClass" border=1px cellspacing=0 align="center" width="100%">';
......
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```

And then, I want to doubleclick table tr, which will call alert method.

But unfortunately,  it worked fail. Here is my js test code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('#cenDiv').on("dblclick","#tbbs #bbs td",function(){
    alert("thsTest");
});
});
```

I know when loading my main web page, tbbs and bbs id are not exit in DOM.So I should rebond them to cenDiv id.But I don't know how. Who can help me?

Comment: Does `$('#cenDiv')` exist in page when code is run and stay in page all the time?

Comment: yes，$('#cenDiv') exist when webpage loading first time

Comment: What you are showing sure seems all correct and should work. Is there any other plugin acting on the table?

Comment: God !!, you are right.The problem is that I have defined a $('#fstDiv') before  $('#cenDiv') in $(document).ready method. but fstDiv is non-existent id in html code. Thank you very much for your kindly heart.